# Composer require failed to install packages

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I have a project with composer that requires vendor/package-1 in the main project composer.json file, vendor/package-1 requires vendor/package-2 in the composer.json of the package-1. I have currently installed version 1.18.11 of vendor/package-1 and version 2.3.2 of vendor/package-2. I want to update to new vendor/package-1 version 1.19.* (that requires version 2.4.* from vendor/package-2) and executing:

```
composer require vendor/package-1:1.19.*
```

Fails and the output I get is

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - vendor/package-1 v1.19.2 requires vendor/package2 2.4.* -> satisfiable by vendor/package2[v2.4.3, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2].
    - vendor/package-1 v1.19.1 requires vendor/package2 2.4.* -> satisfiable by vendor/package2[v2.4.3, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2].
    - vendor/package-1 v1.19.2 requires vendor/package2 2.4.* -> satisfiable by vendor/package2[v2.4.3, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2].
    - Can only install one of: vendor/package2[v2.3.2, v2.4.3].
    - Can only install one of: vendor/package2[v2.4.0, v2.3.2].
    - Can only install one of: vendor/package2[v2.4.1, v2.3.2].
    - Can only install one of: vendor/package2[v2.4.2, v2.3.2].
    - Can only install one of: vendor/package2[v2.4.3, v2.3.2].
    - Installation request for vendor/package2 == 2.3.2.0 -> satisfiable by vendor/package2[v2.3.2].
    - Installation request for vendor/package-1 1.19.* -> satisfiable by vendor/package-1[v1.19.1, v1.19.2].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Does the composer require command need to be specified for all the dependencies? If I try

```
composer require vendor/package-1:1.19.* vendor/package-2:2.4.*
```

It works but it shouldn't be necessary to specify every dependency, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like vendor/package2 is require in a fixed version as 2.3.2 or 2.3.* and cannot be updated to 2.4.

Generally you should try to relax the version requirements to allow for compatible updates. Use the tilde operator for this, require the package2 as ~2.3 (minimum 2.3, update as long as it's not the incompatible version 3). The same applies to package1 as well: If you need the features that are included in the 1.19 line, you'd require ~1.19.

Comment: The thing is that the package1 requires 2.3.* version of package 2 in the 1.18.* version and version 2.4.* in the 1.19.*, but I don't understand why it can't be updated if package1 updates it should update package 2 to the matching version.

Comment: What is your current `composer.json` of the main package saying about both these packages?

Comment: It only has the package1 in the mail composer.json (like this: "vendor/package1":"1.19.*") the package2 is included in the package1's composer.json

Comment: Then I think the problem is that you are only affecting the single package1 which cannot be updated to the required version without updating package2 - which hasn't been authorized by that CLI command. I'd manually change the composer.json to require the correct new version of package1 and then run `composer update` - I'd expect this to work.

Comment: Yes, that works but I was trying to use the require command in order to set manually the version I want to update instead of getting the last one available. Seems that this is not possible, am I right?

Comment: Thanks, you save my day!

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible with:

```
composer require vendor/package-1:1.19.* --update-with-dependencies
```

Comment: wow, that was sometime ago but it looks like a correct response but I can't try it anymore... sorry

Comment: No worries, I replied if anyone else runs into the same problem.